# Append dbf files to one dbf file

Tags: python, python-2.x, arcpy

I have many files in a directory, like `['FredrikstadAvst1.dbf', 'FredrikstadAvst2.dbf', ...]`. I want to write a Python script to concatenate these files into a new `"*.dbf"` file.

I have a Python script that almost does the job. But on the output file it overwrites all the time. So when the job is finished the output file only containes of the last file that is in my directory.

Here is my script:

```
import os, glob, shutil

folder_path = r'C:\Tom\Oppdrag_2019\Pendle\2018'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.dbf')):

    fd = open(filename, 'r')

    List = []
    List.append(fd)

    print filename
wfd = open(r"C:\Tom\Oppdrag_2019\Pendle\FredrikstadAvst.dbf",'a')
shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024*1024*10)
```

Comment: Use the `a` mode for appending to existing file.

Comment: You can't just append dbf files like that, it's not just a bag of bytes

Comment: @HongOoi Oh, perhaps the `dbf` library could be helpful then

Comment: it's not working with a mode instead of wb. It still overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
import os, glob, shutil

folder_path = r'C:\Tom\Oppdrag_2019\Pendle\2018'
wfd = open(r"C:\Tom\Oppdrag_2019\Pendle\FredrikstadAvst.dbf",'w')
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.dbf')):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024*1024*10)
    fd.close()
wfd.close()
```

By opening the file before the loop and closing only after iterating over every dbf file, it shouldn't overwrite. I removed the `List` (which is a reserved keyword so try not to use it) because I can't see what it's being used for here.

Comment: And what would that be?

Comment: It writes everything to a file. But it looks like it's something wrong with the format. When i opens the file in Excel it's no system in the file. I could send a picture, but i don't know how to post a picture here.

Comment: @user15888 you can't append stuff willy-nilly to a dbf file. It doesn't work that way. You have to read the data from each file into a table, then write that table out into a new file.

Comment: Almost work now. But the header writes for every file. I just want the header to write the first time. How to skip the header for each time ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost work now. But the header writes for every file. I just want the header to write the first time. How to skip the header for each time ?